# how to package and start your clojure application?

Tags: clojure

Like many JVM languages, packaging and starting a JVM application can be done in a multitude of ways. What are some solid ways of packaging large clojure projects having lots of both clojure and Java dependencies, for deploying and starting them in production-like environments?

Answer (score 4):

With [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#basic-usage), you can simply package through:

```
lein uberjar
```

This will package all the dependencies and your code into one jar that you can then run via:

```
java -jar uberjar.jar
```

For that to work however, you have to specify a `:main` namespace in your `project.clj`, which will trigger AOT, the latter considered undesirable for other causes such as for [being able to cleanly use `clojure.tools.namespace` over your project](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace#warnings-and-potential-problems). So to avoid AOT, you can skip specifying a `:main` namespace in your `project.clj`, and simply run with the slightly more verbose command:

```
java -jar uberjar.jar clojure.main -m your.main.namespace
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit proposal @bfabry, I have edited your edit.

Comment: We just had a fairly long conversation about this in #clojure, so I thought I better point out that specifying :main in most versions of leiningen triggers AOT. Which can be undesirable for a bunch of reasons, one main one I can think of being it breaks clojure.tools.namespace. So I'd say for most people, the second method is probably more desirable.

Comment: Hope my edits make it a tad more accessible without introducing any error. @bfabry so many thanks for making this knowledge more easily accessible.